# Android Q - Start foreground location service from the background

Tags: android, location, foreground-service, android-10.0

I'm not sure what the behaviour should be in this case.

In the documentation it says that:

> An app is considered to be accessing location in the background unless
>   one of the following conditions is satisfied:
>
> - An activity belonging to the app is visible.
> - The app is running a
>     foreground service that has declared a foreground service type of
>     location.

In the example provided by google, they use an Activity which starts a foreground service **in the foreground**:

https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

In my case, I need to start tracking locations once a bluetooth device is connected to my device (Using a manifest-registered broadcast receiver) - which could be in the background, or after the app terminated).

So, I'm declaring the service in the manifest like they say:

```
 <service
       android:name=".MyForegroundService"
       android:foregroundServiceType="location"
       android:exported="false" />
```

The question is:

In the event when my app receive the broadcast, **while in background / terminated** - If I start the foreground service then, Is it considered **accessing location in the background** or **accessing location in the foreground**?

Should I request for **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION**? or **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** should be enough in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On API 29, if you have an `android:foregroundServiceType` of `"location"`, you do not need `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`. Any location access made while that `Service` is running is considered a "foreground access".

But that assumes you can get the foreground service running. You must be continuing a [user-initiated action](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#continue-user-initiated-action) of some sort. If the `Service` is already running, then it won't be a problem; the `Service` represents the continuation of a user-initiated action. If you need to start it when the BT device connects, well, I'm not sure if that qualifies. That may not work. (If you find out... please suggest an edit!)

An example of an app that *needs* the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission would be one that monitors your GPS position while no `Activities` are visible, and no `"location"`-type foreground service notifications are showing. On Android Q, this wouldn't be allowed to carry on for very long (more than about 30 seconds), without the permission.

I believe the OS also assigns `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` to legacy apps where the user has elected to "Allow all the time" on the location permission dialog.

Comment: Well it seems like i'll have to use the background permission in this case. Thanks!

Comment: so can we lock screen and use foreground service with location type to get location updates without `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` basically?

Comment: @user924 That's correct.